# Solving the Kempner Function in Python - why is this concurrent function continuing after the base case is reached?

Tags: python, function, recurrence

I've been doing Python puzzles and one I have been doing is using a concurrent function to solve the Kempner Function in Python.

The Kempner Function, applied to a composite number, permits to find the smallest integer greater than zero which factorial is exactly divided by the number.

#### For example:

**kempner(6) ➞ 3**

**1! = 1 % 6 > 0**
**2! = 2 % 6 > 0**
**3! = 6 % 6 === 0**

**kempner(10) ➞ 5**

**1! = 1 % 10 > 0**
**2! = 2 % 10 > 0**
**3! = 6 % 10 > 0**
**4! = 24 % 10 > 0**
**5! = 120 % 10 === 0**

There are various ways of doing this, and one of the solutions I have seen is this:

```
def kempner(n, i=1, total=1):
    if total % n == 0:
        return max(1, i-1)
    else:
        return kempner(n, i+1, total*i)
```

I understand the gist of what this is doing, however when I run it through debug mode and see what the variables are doing I can see that when the base condition is reached (`if total % n ==0`) and `return max(1, i-1)` is returned then everything in the `else` clause will continue to run until the function returns to its starting condition (e.g. for `kempner(10)` then `n = 10`, `i = 1`, `total = 1`). Why does it do that? Surely it should stop its recurrence if the base condition has been reached?

This is a fairly abstract issue and is obviously a blind spot in my knowledge. If anyone has any insight I would be grateful.

Comment: It does stop...

Comment: Yes, apologies if that isn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive calls are just like any other function call: when they return, they return control back to whatever called them.

Say you have a series of numbered recursive calls:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4
               Base Case Reached
```

If recursive call 3 called recursive call 4, and recursive call 4 ended at the base case, returning from recursive call 4 will take you back to recursive call 3, because 3 called 4. This is just like any other functions call:

```
def second_func():
    print("Inner")
    return 5

def first_func():
    return second_func()
```

When you return from `second_func`, you return control back to `first_func`, since `first_func` called `second_func`. You don't immediately exit from `second_func` back to `main` or something else. It's the same with recursive calls. The only difference when dealing with recursion is `first_func` and `second_func` are the same function, but that doesn't affect the mechanics of returning.

There is no way (other than using something like exceptions) to exit from the entire call chain at once.

Comment: Thanks for your help here.