# Python return statement doesn't break for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to iterate through an XML structure. My code does seem to work. I checked the debugger and saw that it reached the `return`, but the `for` loop continues.

Looking forward to your advice, thank you!

```
def get_value(root, item):
    for node in root:
        if node.tag == item:
            return node.tag
        else:
            get_value(node, item)
    return 'Item not found in XML'
```

Comment: A loop will not, in any circumstance, continue after reaching a `return`. You must have seen the previous recursive calls completing.

Comment: That is impossible, if a `return` statement was encountered no further iterations of your `for` loop would execute. Note that your function is recursive so be mindful of that when stepping through the debugger.

Comment: If you're expecting the entire chain of recursive calls to exit on the `return`, see my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63885717/solving-the-kempner-function-in-python-why-is-this-concurrent-function-continu/63886225#63886225) question.

Comment: We need a [MCVE] to help here. This code isn't even indented properly. And it's unclear what you expect the `else:` condition to be doing (you make a recursive call and ignore the return value). If you actually reach a `return`, the function always returns immediately unless: 1) The expression associated with the `return` triggers an exception (e.g. `node` has no `tag` attribute) or 2) There is a `with` or `try`/`finally` involved, in which case `with`/`finally` cleanup happens first. Why do you think the loop continues after the `return`?

Comment: It looks you might be returning to previous calls to the function since you appear to be using recursion. There is no circumstance in which *any* code in a function will continue if it is returned from.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies.
The `for` loop didn't continue, thanks to @Carcigenicate and @CoryKramer i figured out, the loop didnt continue but the other calls were completing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the issue is, you are calling the same function is else statement. So, if it enters in else block, it might go on recursively.
Try to amend your code, avoiding calling the function from within. Also, you might need to place return inside  for loop, highlighted below

```
def get_value(root, item):
    for node in root:
        if node.tag == item:
            return node.tag
        else:
            get_value(node, item) ---> This is the problem
        return 'Item not found in XML'
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a `return` statement right when you start recursion calls. Meaning it would go on forever until max recurison limit is reached or run out of memory.

change your code like this

```
def get_value(root, item):
    for node in root:
        if node.tag == item:
            return node.tag
        else:
            return get_value(node, item)
    return 'Item not found in XML'
```